# Edit a list item in PowerPhell

Tags: list, powershell

```
foreach($list in $lists){

if ($list.title -eq 'PerformanceDevelopment'){
foreach($item in $list.items){

if ($item.title -like $Employee+'*'){
$OldLineManager = $item["Manager Name"]
$item["Manager Name"] = "test manager"
$item.Update()
```

Here is a snippet from my code.

I am trying to edit a item in a list, however the code above is not working. I am using SharePoint 2010. No errors are given it just doesn't work.

Comment: What is the type of Manager Name column?

Comment: single line of text

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Internal Name` of the column. Should be something like this in your case: `Manager_x0020_Name`.

Comment: nope doesn't work, it brings back the Manager Name fine, its just when I then try and edit it

Answer (score 1):

If your column type is Person or Group, then you have to update it following way

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser = $spWeb.EnsureUser("domain\username")         
$item["Manager Name"] = $spuser  
$item.Update()
```

And make sure following statement is executing

```
if ($item.title -like $Employee+'*')
```

Answer (score 0):

My column was read only so I had to add this first

```
$list.Fields["Manager Name"].ReadOnlyField = $false
$list.Fields["Manager Name"].Update()
```